# How to run multiple commands in parallel and get their outputs(pass/fail)?

Tags: python, subprocess, python-multiprocessing

I  am trying to run the 3 print commands in parallel and get the output of all the three commands so that I can decide whether its a PASS or FAIL? currently the output is `['', '', '']` where as I expect the output of print commands, where am I going wrong?

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool 
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, call


cmds = ["print username1","print username2 ","print username3"]
def function_create_cmds(cmd):
    proc = Popen(cmd , shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    (output, error) = proc.communicate()
    return output

# Make the Pool of workers
pool = ThreadPool(3) 
results = pool.map(function_create_cmds, cmds)
#close the pool and wait for the work to finish 
pool.close() 
pool.join() 
print results
```

OUTPUT:-

```
['', '', '']
```

Comment: What os are you using? What does 'print username1` do on your os?

Comment: change your `return output` statement to `return error` to see what is going wrong

Answer (score 1):

There isn't anything wrong with your code. It's just that the `print` command normally has no output if you have your printer setup properly (assuming this is run in Windows).

Replace all your `print` commands with `echo` and you'll see the following output:

```
[b'username1\r\n', b'username2 \r\n', b'username3\r\n']
```

If you wish to capture any errors from the `print` command, you can redirect standard error to standard output with:

```
proc = Popen(cmd , shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

Comment: The only other `print` command I know that comes preinstalled on anything modern is Debian/Ubuntu, where it's an alias to `mailcap`—and that also normally has no output. (Even if your printer _isn't_ setup properly, it'll just dump warnings and/or errors to stderr and nothing to stdout.) So, I don't know if you even need the caveat about assuming Windows.

Comment: am running this on a MacBook ,so its Mac OS

Comment: @user3508811 Like John Anderson has pointed out, there may be an error from the `print` command but you're not returning it. To capture both output and error in one returning value, you can redirect standard error to standard output with `proc = Popen(cmd , shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)` instead.